# Pdf hyperlinks are not working in my localhost

Tags: php, pdf, xampp, localhost

I have multiple pdf files in different webpages, when I test them in my localhost the webpage appears fine but when I click on the href links that directs to a  pdf file nothing happens (here is the bar address  : http://localhost/rootfolder/Centralafricanrepublic.html)
However, when I open the same webpage directly from my computer (here the bar address is:  file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/rootfolder/index.html) the pdf file works.

Please let me know what I am doing wrong for my pdf files not to appear in my local host?

N.B:

1. I need to make sure that the pdf files work because I am planning to export my localhost database from phpmyadmin and import it to my live website.
2. my apache server is running.
3. all my pdf hyperlinks are written like this :

> ```
>   <a href= "C:\xampp\htdocs\rootfolder\Algeria\banking and finance law\Loi 90-10 relative à la monnaie et au crédit.pdf" type="application/pdf" target="_blank">Loi n°90-10 relative à la monnaie et au crédit</a>
> ```

4. I have more than 60 webpages that contains dozens of pdf files, I would really appreciate it if the solution is simple and wouldn't require to edit manually each page/pdf file.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: _Terminology matters, specially when asking questions_ `phpMyAdmin` is a tool written in PHP it is not a Database manager! Probably you mean MySQL but possible maraiDB

Comment: Never use a Windows Drive path reference like `href= "C:\xampp\htdocs\rootfolder .......` This will NEVER translate well to the location you get given on a hosted server, even if it is a Windows Server but definitely not if its a Linux server

Comment: Try changing the format to `/rootfolder/Algeria/...` instead of `C:\xampp\htdocs\rootfolder\Algeria\...`.

Comment: If you launch a page with a `file:///....` reference, you are **not** using your web server (apache) at all, you are loading directly off the file system. It will run HTML and Javascript, but any Server Side Code like PHP you may have will just be **ignored**

Comment: @waterloomatt probably without the leading `/`

Comment: @RiggsFolly that didn't work either. Is because the way I wrote my path reference means that the pdf files won't show on my live website ? even if I export my localhost and import it to the website?